# From local to global database

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, phpmyadmin

I have a problem, I want do create a "global database" which should be accessible from all computers anywhere but I can't find an solution. I have made an database with MAMP and phpMyAdmin and it's working fine on my computer only but when i try to login from other computers i get the message "java.sql.SQLException: Acces denied for user "rood@localhost" (using password: YES)".

this is my code for the database connection, it is a login frame.

```
   //Login button 
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Login");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            try {

 //             connection to databse
                Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myusers", "root", "root");

                String query = "select * from brugere where username=? and password=?";
                PreparedStatement myStnt = myConn.prepareStatement(query);
                myStnt.setString(1, textField.getText());
                myStnt.setString(2, passwordField.getText());

////            Create statement
                ResultSet myRs = myStnt.executeQuery();
//                  
                int count = 0;
                while (myRs.next()) {
                    count = count + 1; 
                }

                if (count == 1) {
                    myRs.close();
                    myStnt.close();
                    myConn.close();

                    MainMenu mm = new MainMenu();
                    mm.setVisible(true);
                    frame.dispose();

                    frame.dispose();
                }
                else if (count > 1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate Username and password");
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry wrong username or password");

                }           

            }catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(288, 96, 89, 67);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your problem not in your codes, you need to create new user "(accessable from any machine)" on your database, look at the picture :**

[image: picture]

**because of your account only can access from localhost.**

I hope this help you.Good Luck.